# combine multiple regex into one for comma removing

Tags: php, regex

`$reg1 = preg_replace('/(?<!\d),(?=\s+\d)/', '', $text);
$reg2 = preg_replace('/,\s*$/', '', $reg1);
$reg3 = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $reg2);`

I have these three regex-replace calls. Can I combine those in one?
The first one removes commas after strings and before digits.
The second one removes a comma at the end.
The third one trims whitespace.

Comment: Please add some sample input strings and expected result.

Comment: Do you need to combine them for some reason? Is performance suffering? For simplification of the second regex you can try out `rtrim($reg1, ',');`. I can't read regex very well but the third one could use `trim($reg2);`. What do you need to happen if a string looks like this `, an amazing, string to mess up your, 10th day , `?

Comment: `'hulk, 33,' => 'hulk 33'`
`'test     3 ,' => 'test 3'`

Answer (score 2):

The first two can be combined like:

```
$reg1 = preg_replace('/(?<!\d),\s*(?=\d|$)/', '', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the different replacement values, you can only group your first 2 regex with an "or" condition. `preg_replace` also allow multiple replacements, so you can pass the 3rd regex as a separate argument.

```
$result = preg_replace(array('/((?<!\d),(?=\s+\d))|(,\s*$)/', '(\s\s+)'), array('', ' '), $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass all three to `preg_replace`:

```
$patterns = array('/(?<!\d),(?=\s+\d)/', '/,\s*$/', '/\s\s+/');
$replacements = array('', '', ' ');

$result = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $text);
```